# QPainter crashes while using the QPropertyAnimation

Tags: pyqt, qpainter, qpropertyanimation

I want to use the graphicsOpacityEffect in propertyAnimation for a QFrame that contains a label with a pixmap. My code is:

```py
eff = QGraphicsOpacityEffect(frame)
widget.setGraphicsEffect(eff)            

animation = QPropertyAnimation(eff, b"opacity")
animation.setStartValue(0)
animation.setEndValue(1)
animation.setDuration(500)
animation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.InBack)
animation.start(QPropertyAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)
```

Everything works, but when I hover the label, then the images disappear and I get the warning as below:

```py
QPainter::setWorldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::setWorldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.
QPainter::translate: Painter not active
QPainter::worldTransform: Painter not active
QWidgetEffectSourcePrivate::pixmap: Painter not active
QPainter::worldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::setWorldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::setWorldTransform: Painter not active
QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: whats is widget?

Comment: Widget can be any QWidget. In this case it is QFrame.

Answer (score 2):

You should delete previously set **QGraphicsOpacityEffect** to the widget as follow before assigning new **QGraphicsOpacityEffect** to widget or its child:

```
connect(animation,&QPropertyAnimation::finished,[=](){
           eff->deleteLater();
});
```

As the error says:

> QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.

There are two or more painter trying to paint widget at same time.

**Background:**

**QGraphicsEffect** is the base class of **QGraphicsOpacityEffect** and for any graphics effects library in Qt. If you look into **QGraphicsEffect** source it uses QPainter for drawing. Hence user using any of graphics effects class on any widget implies he is initiating one **QPainter** to render effects and its obvious that we cannot draw using more than one **QPainter** at a time on a device or surface.